# Simple query with date type requires explicit conversion to_date of date

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

My question is, I have a table which contains a column called myDateColumn (for example) which is of the type date:

I can confirm `desc myTable` contains this line:

```
myDateColumn  NOT NULL     DATE
```

However, when I try to select all the data that is between certain dates, for example:

```
select * from myTable 
where myDateColumn 
between to_date('13-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('15-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

I get null results no matter what, even though I am sure some data exists within this specific date range.

The fix for it I discovered was to explicitly convert myDateColumn to a date:

```
select myDateColumn from myTable 
where to_date(myDateColumn) 
between to_date('13-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('15-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

which returns the correct results, but it is already a date type!  Why do I need to explicitly convert a date column to date before doing the `between` logical comparison?

The reason why I ask is because this select/ where will be part of a stored procedure selecting data within a specific date range to be run on a big table partitioned by date, with more than ten million rows, and if I can avoid explictly converting each myDateColumn of each row, then I might be able to save some query time, in theory.

Or is there a more correct way to run this comparison to select data within a date range?

Thank you.

Update:  Leigh suggested in the answer to diagnose the table for something inconsistent with his query.  The result of his query was:

```
myDateColumn    TO_DATE(myDateColumn)   TO_CHAR(myDateColumn,'DD-MON-YYHH.MI.SSPM') TO_CHAR(myDateColumn,'YYYY')  
14-Feb-11   14-Feb-11   14-FEB-11 12.00.00 AM   0011
14-Feb-11   14-Feb-11   14-FEB-11 12.00.00 AM   0011
14-Feb-11   14-Feb-11   14-FEB-11 12.00.00 AM   0011
14-Feb-11   14-Feb-11   14-FEB-11 12.00.00 AM   0011
14-Feb-11   14-Feb-11   14-FEB-11 12.00.00 AM   0011
```

Indicating that the reason the `between` clause was not working, is because none of the data would fall in the query interval, since the year was 0011, during the Roman Empire :)

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why are you using 2-digit years? Have we not learned anything from Y2K?

Comment: I suggest using date literals in ISO format as: between date '2011-02-13' and date '2011-02-15'

Comment: you know, a lot of programmers now were not around to fix programming issues in 2000....  So I foresee a repeat in 2100, good eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your belief that this should not be necessary is correct based on your assumptions.  Normally this means the assumptions should be rechecked (unless there is data corruption or a bug).  If you run the following you should get the same results from the first query as the second:

```
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (
   SELECT to_date('01-FEB-2011','DD-MON-YYYY')+level myDateColumn 
   FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=120);

select * from t1 
where myDateColumn 
between to_date('13-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('15-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');

select myDateColumn from t1 
where to_date(myDateColumn) 
between to_date('13-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('15-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

To check some of the assumptions, can you show the results of the following query?

```
SELECT myDateColumn, to_date(myDateColumn)
   , to_char(myDateColumn,'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS PM'), to_char(myDateColumn,'YYYY') 
FROM myTable
WHERE to_date(myDateColumn)
BETWEEN to_date('13-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('15-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

The first three columns should all show identical information and the last should verify that the year is correct.

Comment: Leigh... you were right to check this... posting the update in the question.  The entire table is actually vulnerable to the Y2K problem...  (or Y2100 I guess )

Answer (score 3):

All dates in Oracle have a time component.

I'm pretty sure you want all rows between the 13th and the 15th *included*. However, when you write:

```
BETWEEN to_date('13-02-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('15-02-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

you select only all date up to the `15-02-2011` at midnight. All rows later that day won't be selected.

What is happening is that when you use `TO_DATE` on a date, it will be converted to VARCHAR2 and then converted back to a date. The net effect will be a truncation to your date format as shown:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char(to_date(sysdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') trunc,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') not_trunc
  3    from dual;

TRUNC               NOT_TRUNC
------------------- -------------------
23/10/2012 00:00:00 23/10/2012 15:15:32
```

So your two clauses are not equivalent at all. The second one selects the whole day feb, 15th whereas the first one only selects the first second of the day.

I suggest you use the following constructions when writing date range:

```
WHERE dat >= to_date('13-02-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  AND dat < to_date('16-02-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Also don't use `MON` or `DAY` format in your code since they are dependent upon language. Don't use `YY` since this can be confusing (ever heard of the Y2k bug?). Both formats are ok to display information to your users of course.

Comment: I had commented that this was incorrect because your query from dual for me was returning a time portion.  The difference, and the critical component to your likely correct answer, is the nls_date_format setting.

Comment: @Leigh I have found that often `to_date(date)` goes unnoticed in code review but is a bug waiting to happen (because the behaviour is dependent upon an NLS setting)

Comment: Indeed, to_date/to_char should always have a format specified.

Comment: I see.. I am looking at your solution, so far still encountering the same issue, the suggested solution produces a null result, doesn't matter what the interval is for some reason...  but when I convert myDateColumn explicitly, that seemed to do it....  Looking at Leigh Riffel's solution as well, we may have come upon some new information... YTK bug related! :)

Comment: Thank you for the contribution as well, in the final query version, have noted the intricacy of the midnight setting of the to_date...  the major issue was that the table had a fundamentally outdated date formatting style...